# count partial duplicates in Vec of structs with a custom function

Tags: rust

So let's say I have the following example:

```
struct Client {
    email: String,
    phone: String,
    details: String
}

fn main() {
    let mut clients: Vec<Client> = Vec::new();

    clients.push(Client {
        email: "john@gmail.com".to_string(),
        phone: "0123456789".to_string(),
        details: "custom details".to_string(),
    });

    clients.push(Client {
        email: "john@gmail.com".to_string(),
        phone: "0123456789".to_string(),
        details: "other details".to_string(),
    });

    clients.push(Client {
        email: "james@gmail.com".to_string(),
        phone: "9876543210".to_string(),
        details: "test".to_string(),
    });  
}
```

What would be the best (Rust idiomatic) way to count partial duplicates in this vector by checking `email` and `phone` in the `Client`? For instance - in the example above one duplicate would be found.

Comment: You could use `.map()` to extract the email and phone as a tuple. Then the problem is reduced to counting full duplicates.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option is to create a `HashSet` with `(email, phone)` for each client. As `HashSet` keep only unique elements, we can get the number of duplicates elements with the difference of the number of elements in `clients` an in the set:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

struct Client {
    email: String,
    phone: String,
    details: String,
}

fn main() {
    let mut clients: Vec<Client> = Vec::new();

    clients.push(Client {
        email: "john@gmail.com".to_string(),
        phone: "0123456789".to_string(),
        details: "custom details".to_string(),
    });

    clients.push(Client {
        email: "john@gmail.com".to_string(),
        phone: "0123456789".to_string(),
        details: "other details".to_string(),
    });

    clients.push(Client {
        email: "james@gmail.com".to_string(),
        phone: "9876543210".to_string(),
        details: "test".to_string(),
    });

    // use as_str to get a `&str` from a String to avoid copying the string
    let uniques: HashMap<_, _> = clients.iter()
        .map(|c| (c.email.as_str(), c.phone.as_str()))
        .collect();

    let num_dups = clients.len() - uniques.len();

    assert_eq!(1, num_dups);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You will often want to know *which* were the duplicates. In that case, a straight-forward extension of [the `HashSet` solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37700229/155423) can be used:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

struct Client {
    email: String,
    phone: String,
    details: String,
}

impl Client {
    fn key<'a>(&'a self) -> (&'a str, &'a str) {
        (&self.email, &self.phone)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let clients = vec![Client {
                           email: "john@gmail.com".to_string(),
                           phone: "0123456789".to_string(),
                           details: "custom details".to_string(),
                       },
                       Client {
                           email: "john@gmail.com".to_string(),
                           phone: "0123456789".to_string(),
                           details: "other details".to_string(),
                       },
                       Client {
                           email: "james@gmail.com".to_string(),
                           phone: "9876543210".to_string(),
                           details: "test".to_string(),
                       }];

    let mut keyed = HashMap::new();
    for c in &clients {
        keyed.entry(c.key()).or_insert(vec![]).push(c)
    }

    for (k, v) in &keyed {
        if v.len() > 1 {
            println!("Key {:?} has {} duplicates!", k, v.len());
        }
    }
}
```

Note the use of a method on `Client` to keep the keying logic in one place,  the use of `vec![]` to reduce the amount of explicit mutability needed, and there's no need to specify the type of `clients` as it can be inferred.